# Plot PDF of Pareto distribution in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, openturns

I have a specific [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution).  For example,

```
Pareto(beta=0.00317985, alpha=0.147365, gamma=1.0283)
```

which I obtained from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64723239/2203144) and now I want to plot a graph of its Probability Density Function (PDF) in [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/).  So I believe that the x-axis will be all positive real numbers, and the y-axis will be the same.

How exactly can I obtain the appropriate PDF information and plot it?  **Programmatically obtaining the mathematical PDF function or coordinates is a requirement for this question.**

---

UPDATE:

The `drawPDF` method returns a Graph object that contains coordinates for the PDF.  However, I don't know how to access these coordinates programmatically.  I certainly don't want to convert the object to a string nor use a regex to pull out the information:

```
In [45]: pdfg = distribution.drawPDF()

In [46]: pdfg
Out[46]: class=Graph name=pdf as a function of X0 implementation=class=GraphImplementation name=pdf as a function of X0 title= xTitle=X0 yTitle=PDF axes=ON grid=ON legendposition=topright legendFontSize=1
 drawables=[class=Drawable name=Unnamed implementation=class=Curve name=Unnamed derived from class=DrawableImplementation name=Unnamed legend=X0 PDF data=class=Sample name=Unnamed implementation=class=Sam
pleImplementation name=Unnamed size=129 dimension=2 data=[[-1610.7,0],[-1575.83,0],[-1540.96,0],[-1506.09,0],[-1471.22,0],[-1436.35,0],[-1401.48,0],[-1366.61,0],...,[-1331.7,6.95394e-06],[2852.57,6.85646e-06]] color
=red fillStyle=solid lineStyle=solid pointStyle=none lineWidth=2]
```

Comment: Jean A.'s answer in the post you shared has plotted the PDF, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Look for the example code called "Display the probability density function (pdf):" at scipy's [scipy.stats.pareto](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pareto.html).  They use a linspace for x between the 1st and 99th percentile.

Comment: @TYZ No, that method does not use `matplotlib`.  I would like to get the actual function or coordinates of the PDF in hand, and then feed them into a graphing software of my choice.

Comment: @TYZ Thank you for asking!  You have made it apparent that my question was unclear.

Comment: @mareoraft Will this work? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pareto.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to perform different tasks:

1. To plot the PDF
2. To compute the PDF at a single point
3. To compute the PDF for a range of values

Each of these needs requires a different script. Please let me detail them.

I first create the `Pareto` distribution:

```
import openturns as ot
import numpy as np
beta = 0.00317985
alpha = 0.147365
gamma = 1.0283
distribution = ot.Pareto(beta, alpha, gamma)
print("distribution", distribution)
```

To plot the PDF, use `drawPDF()` method. This creates a `ot.Graph` which can be viewed directly in Jupyter Notebook or IPython. We can force the creation of the plot with `View`:

```
import openturns.viewer as otv
graph = distribution.drawPDF()
otv.View(graph)
```

This plots:

[image: PDF of Pareto distribution]

To compute the PDF at a single point, use `computePDF(x)`, where `x` is a `ot.Point()`. This can also be a Python `list` or `tuple` or 1D numpy `array`, as the conversion is automatically managed by OpenTURNS:

```
x = 500.0
y = distribution.computePDF(x)
print("y=", y)
```

The previous script prints:

```
y= 5.0659235352823877e-05
```

To compute the PDF for a range of values, we can use the `computePDF(x)`, where x is a `ot.Sample()`. This can also be a Python `list` of lists or a 2D numpy `array`, as the conversion is automatically managed by OpenTURNS.

```
x = ot.Sample([[v] for v in np.linspace(0.0, 1000.0)])
y = distribution.computePDF(x)
print("y=", y)
```

The previous script prints:

```
y= 
 0 : [ 0           ]
 1 : [ 0.00210511  ]
 [...]
 49 : [ 2.28431e-05 ]
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for this answer!